# Python. How to modify/replace elements of a list which is a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries:

```
D_1 = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E', 6: 'F', 7: 'G', 8: 'H', 9: 'I', 10: 'J', 11: 'K', 12: 'L', 13: 'M', 14: 'N', 15: 'O', 16: 'P', 17: 'Q', 18: 'R', 19: 'S', 20: 'T', 21: 'U', 22: 'V', 23: 'W', 24: 'X', 25: 'Y', 26: 'Z'}

D_2 = {1: ['A', 'A', 'R', 'O', 'N'], 2: ['A', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'Y'], 3: ['A', 'B', 'B', 'I', 'E']}
```

My task is to replace the letters in values of D2 with corresponding keys from D1. For example I would want the first key and value pair in D2 to look like this : {1:[1,1,19,16,15]}
I have modified D2 where i made the values into lists instead of strings thinking that it would make my task easier.

Comment: Modifying `D_1` such as `{'A': 1, 'B': 2, ...}` makes more sense. You won't gain much by converting strings to lists as strings are also sequences in Python.

Comment: This will do `ord('Z')-65+1` inplace of creating D_1 you could have directly use ord. to replace

Comment: I think I may have have not explained my problem clearly...

Comment: @AbramoAbramov what is the original `D_2`?

Comment: @Mushif Ali Nawaz 1{1: [AARON] ,..................}

Comment: @AbramoAbramov is AARON a `list` with 1 element? I guess it would a string?

Comment: @Mushif Ali Nawaz it was a dictionary where the values were strings...i just showed one key value pair here...there are more than 1000 in the dict...

Comment: @AbramoAbramov something like this: `{1: 'AARON', 2: 'ABBEY', 3: 'ABBIE'}` probably? If yes, then you can try my solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ord`

```
D_2 = {1: ['A', 'A', 'R', 'O', 'N'], 2: ['A', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'Y'], 3: ['A', 'B', 'B', 'I', 'E']}

{k: [ord(val)-64 for val in v] for (k, v) in D_2.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
{1: [1, 1, 18, 15, 14], 2: [1, 2, 2, 5, 25], 3: [1, 2, 2, 9, 5]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
dd = {v:k for (k, v) in D_1.items()}
{x: [dd[a] for a in y] for (x, y) in D_2.items()}
```

First line reverts `D_1`. Second line applies `dd` to values in `D_2`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `D_1` is redundant. What you can do here is to use `ascii_uppercase`:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

{k: [ascii_uppercase.index(i) + 1 for i in v] for k, v in D_2.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: [1, 1, 18, 15, 14], 2: [1, 2, 2, 5, 25], 3: [1, 2, 2, 9, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
m = map(lambda v:[{v: k for k, v in D_1.items()}[e] for e in v], D_2.values())
```

encapsulated in a map and create the new dictionary when useful:

```py
dict(list(enumerate(m, start=1)))
# {1: [1, 1, 18, 15, 14], 2: [1, 2, 2, 5, 25], 3: [1, 2, 2, 9, 5]}
```